# Mongoose Import Json Export with IDs

Tags: json, mongodb

I want to import for unit tests a fixed limited subset of my actual database. So I exported my database with the mongo shell into mydata.json. Now I want to read exactly this Array of JSON files into my db, with keeping the ids.

**1st:** I already fail on reading the JSON Export, how to fix this?

```
if !db?
  mongoose.connect(configDB.url,{auth:{authdb:configDB.authdb}}, (err)->
    if (err)
      console.log(err)
  )
  db = mongoose.connection
  db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'))
  db.once('open', () ->
    console.log "Database established"
    #Delete all data and seed new data
    SomeModel = require(applicationDir + 'node/models/some.model.js')
    SomeModel.remove({}, (err) ->
      console.log('collection somes removed seeding new one')
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../../mongo/seed-for-test/somes.json','utf-8', (err,fileData) ->
        console.log typeof fileData
        fileData = JSON.parse(fileData)
        console.log fileData.length
        # new SomeModel(fileData).save((err) ->
        #   if err?
        #     return console.log err
        #   console.log('somes saved')
        # )
      )
    )
  )
```

**error**

```
string
undefined:2
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "551d82e30287751fa2f2dfb2" }, "prooven" : true, "title" :
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
  at Object.parse (native)
  at /Users/MasterG/Desktop/PROJEKTE/lek/specs/backend/mongo.service.spec.js:37:27
  at fs.js:336:14
  at /Users/MasterG/Desktop/PROJEKTE/lek/node_modules/wiredep/node_modules/bower-config/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:104:5
  at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:99:15)
```

**2nd**
If I uncomment the lower part will it work or is there anything else I need to do.

**EDIT**

The export does not give back a valid array of json objects. The `--jsonArray` flag has to be used when exporting.

Answer (score 1):

This works with exporting with the flag `--jsonArray` but it looks wrong to me. Also the .json file is not formated as nicely as before. And I need to add some extra logic to check if the last entry was saved.

```
ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId
SomeModel = require(applicationDir + 'node/models/some.model.js')

if !db?
  mongoose.connect(configDB.url,{auth:{authdb:configDB.authdb}}, (err)->
    if (err)
      console.log(err)
  )
  db = mongoose.connection
  db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'))
  db.once('open', () ->
    console.log "Database established"
    #Delete all data and seed new data
    SomeModel.remove({}, (err) ->
      console.log('collection somes removed seeding new one')
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../../mongo/seed-for-test/somes.json','utf-8', (err,fileData) ->
        fileData = JSON.parse(fileData)
        for singleFileData in fileData
          singleFileData._id = new ObjectId(singleFileData._id.$oid)
          new SomeModel(singleFileData).save((err) ->
            if err?
              return console.log err
            console.log('somes saved')
          )
      )
    )
  )
```